# Django migrate says OK but tables in the remote database are not created

Tags: postgresql, django-models, migration

We have made a new version of our website with Django 5.0.2 and Postgresql 16.01 on a remote server.
We have run ‘makemigrations’ and the migration files are created.

```
(venv) usr@tsa-nl:~/tsa3/tsap$ python manage.py showmigrations
accounts
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
etc.
```

But when we run ‘migrate’ to create the tables in the new database, the remote database is still empty although migrate returns OK.

```
(venv) usr@tsa-nl:~/tsa3/tsap$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, companies, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying accounts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying companies.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
etc.
```

Since the response is 'OK', Django must have created the table 'django_migrations'.
When we disable the remote connection, Django migrate still returns 'OK'.
That means that Django creates the tables on the local machine, but we cannot find them.

We use dj-database-url-2.1.0 and have stored the connection string in the .env file
Settings.py (there is only 1 settings.py in the project):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

The .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://tsadb:xxxxxxxxxxx@dbaas-db-xxxxxxxxx-do-user-xxxxx-0.c.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060/tsadb?sslmode=require
```

We added the flag migrate --database=default to make sure we are using the right connection string, but still no luck.

Then, we have taken the code from 'sqlmigrations' and have created the tables in the remote database manually. That worked, but having to alter tables manually is a no-go.

In our current website with Django 3.1.7 and Postgresql 15 the migrate process works fine.

How can we find out where Django has stored the tables and
what must we do to let Django create the tables on the remote database?

We appreciate your help.